# Inductor calcualtions to limit inrush and avoid oscillations in power line

Tags: inductor, oscillation, inrush-current

I want to design a circuit that is able to supply my load with 12V at 2.3A for around 10ms when the power is switched off.

The capacitor size will therefore be 23000 uF, assuming a 1V sag. Applying this capacitor in this way will not be a very good idea during power-up. So I want to add some inductance in order to limit the current that is supplied at start-up to slowly charge the cap. I do not want to use a resistor as this wastes power.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1U3K1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**How do I calculate the inductor value so I do:**

1. Limit the inrush
2. To prevent any oscillations in the power line, the power supply has a switching frequency of 250 kHz

Comment: When the power is switched off, is it the enable of U1, or is V1 removed?  If it's the latter, then you're better off putting the large cap on the input. \$U=0.5CV^2\$, that squared term is pretty powerful.  No pun intended.

Comment: @Aaron sorry by switched off, I mean the power supply goes into its protection mode and cuts the output off. The power supply is 12V 1.2A and goes into protection mode at 2A

Comment: What is U1? The power supply? Or regulator? Which kind of device it is?

Comment: @JoeyB Dropping 12 V at 2.3 A (when the power is *not* off) seems to also be wasteful, if U1 is a linear regulator. Is it? More, when powering down (turning off) and getting another 10 mS of time out of things, you are then still throwing away 11 V on the capacitor, or about 1.4 Joules. Not sure if you can do anything about that, of course. But there it remains as part of the "budget." What is U1 and what does the 24 V source look like? Also, what does the cycling look like, turn-on, on time, and turn-off, to next cycling...?

Comment: @jonk the power supply has a switching frequency of 250 kHz as mentioned in point 2. So U1 is a switching power supply.

Comment: @Justme It is a SMPS with a switching frequency of 250 kHz

Comment: @JoeyB Thanks. That thought had crossed my mind after I wrote. I guess I'm now kind of wondering if you'd consider some kind of *tracking* power supply IC that would allow you to control the turn-on timing. There are also some external MOSFET analog circuits that function as part of the usual FB pin that can also be used for this purpose when the IC itself doesn't directly support it.

Comment: @jonk I do not have another PSU to use I have this one that is why I have this question. Can you assist with the question I have asked?

Comment: @JoeyB I guess I'm still coming to grips with this minimalist "behavioral" diagram and your focus on the inductor itself. You already know, I suspect, that \$\frac{\text{d}\,I}{\text{d} t}=\frac{V_{_\text{L}}}{L}\$. I'm not sure I can add much to that. So I probably cannot assist further.

Comment: What is the source capacitance of the 24V when off? is this an unknown with a power failure?

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 sorry by switched off, I mean the power supply goes into its protection mode and cuts the output off. The power supply is 12V 1.2A and goes into protection mode at 2A

Comment: I mean the source of power from 24V and also what is the load impedance range?

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 the first I do not know, the second part the load impedance can range from 10 ohm to 5.2 ohm

Comment: The obvious solution since you are using a switching supply is to use soft start. The switching supply should have it's own inductor so your extra one is superfluous. Tell us more about the switchmode supply.